# Как пользоваться методами и классами с developer.android?

Tags: java, android

Так вышло, что мне нужно писать приложение под Android вообще без изучения предмета. Поэтому далее буду выглядеть как полный идиот.
Мне нужно получить три характеристики: уникальный идентификатор базовой станции LTE, её PCI и уровень RSRP в данный момент. 
И я даже нашел на developer.android нужные методы и классы. Но без знания фундаментальной базы ООП, я просто не могу понять, как вызывать эти методы.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityLte.html

Вот здесь указан метод getPci(). Это то, что нужно, но меня не хватает на большее, чем прямой его вызов:

int i = CellIdentityLte.getPci();

Само собой, это неправильно.

Не мог бы кто-то объяснить принцип, как я должен трактовать и использовать указанное в developer.android?

Answer (score 5):

Смотрите, есть определенная проблема, например использование сервисов в android. Я ищу в гугле тему про сервисы. Смотрю примеры. Если всь фунционал который приведен в примере меня устраивает, я пользуюсь примером. Если что то нужно расширить или посмотреть весь функционал работы с сервисами, я захожу на developer.android. Там приведена полная (но не разжованная) информация про те или иные функции. Есть даже примеры. Еще если вы запутались в чем-то или непонятна ошибка, тоже можно посмотреть на сайте. Там в основном информация про методы, классы, наследники и тп. Это по поводу developer.android. К этому всему вам нужна еще Java. Смотрите как делают проекты на GitHub опытные разработчики, тоже хорошо помогает освоить.

Comment: Тема узкоспециализированная, примеров не находил. 
Как быть конкретно с этим методом?

Comment: @Дмитрий унаследуйтесь в вашем класе от CellIdentityLte и исполузуйте его методы. Или попробуйте еще:  `CellIdentityLte  lte = new CellIdentityLte(); int pci = lte.getPci();`

Comment: Ваш вариант тоже не работает, увы :(
И я не понимаю, что значит "Унаследуйтесь". :( Глупый.